# English style for non-English CultureInfo

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, telerik, globalization

Modern web controls like `telerik:RadNumericTextBox` gives the ability to set cultured currency

```
<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="cbo_FromPrice" runat="server" culture="Arabic (Qatar)" Type="Currency"></telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
```

The displayed number will be like :

**2500,00 .ر.ق**

Is there anyway to get culture like English (Qatar), I expect result Qatari Riyal like:

**2500,00 .Q.R**

Answer (score -1):

What about English (Qatar)?

Although it doesn't exists!